# How to get last inserted value of a Specific column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Is there any way where we could us IDENT_CURRENT() to retrieve a specific value from a specific column

Comment: What task do you want to implement ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I want an hint to retrieve a last entered Value in a specific column

Comment: For Ex:

If there is a table of company Product where product code is unique I.D.

Comment: IDENT_CURRENT  gives a last number of row.


I want to show my primary key as that result

Comment: Your question is not clear. by SQL 2005 do you mean SQL SERVER 2005? What is the relevant table structure? what column are you talking about? what value do you want?

Comment: Generally impossible without auditing trigges.

Answer (score 0):

**We will consider that you need to retrieve product_code from product table-**

```
  SELECT LAST (product_code) FROM product;
```

Or else you can try this

```
  SELECT Ident_Current(product_code) AS Alias from product;
```

Comment: Its Giving following error

'LAST' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Hey Bro. Your 2nd Answer worked a bit.
But it gave me the whole column with null reference.

Thnx

Comment: You can try this also-- Select TOP 1 product_code from product
order by product_code DESC;

Comment: It will give last entered value in specific column.

Answer (score -1):

according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx

You could use

```
SELECT Ident_Current('column_name') AS Alias;
```

For example if you are trying to retrieve a product Id from your company_product table you could do:

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('company_product.comp_prod_id') as CURRENT_PRODUCT_ID;
```

This would give you the last entered primary key if your primary key column name was comp_prod_id and it would set the alias CURRENT_PRODUCT_ID to your result

The correct format might be

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT ('tablename.columnname');
```

But I am not sure as I do not have anything to test it on at my disposal

Comment: I tried Your Statement But It's Giving an invalid column error

Comment: Sorry you need to add quotes around the column name, I forgot to add those

You might also need to add a space after ident_current but I am not sure as I do not have a database at my disposal to test these queries